# What is the difference between SQLAlchemy session.remove() and session.close()?

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy

I don't know the difference between `db.session.remove()` and `db.session.close()`.
I am a beginner in using SQLAlchemy and I have the following problem: after completing operations in a MySQL database which of the two commands should be used? Can both be used at the same time?

I use it in a flask app where the SQLAlchemy engine has pool size = 30. I want to manage session better to avoid exception QueuePool limit overflow.

Comment: Use `session.remove` if you are using scoped sessions (Flask-SQLAlchemy uses these), `session.close` otherwise.  `session.remove` calls `session.close` and removes the session from the registry of scoped sessions; there is no analogous registry for non-scoped sessions.